# Function to recode multiple variables conditional on other variables

Tags: r, conditional-statements, recode

I have a dataset with multiple variables. Each question has the actual survey answer and three other characteristics. So there are four variables for each question. I want to specify if `Q135_L ==1` , leave `Q135_RT` as it is, otherwise code it as `NA`. I can do that with an `ifelse` statement.

```
df$Q135_RT <- ifelse(df$Q135_L == 1, df$Q22_RT, NA)
```

However, I have hundreds of variables and the names are not related. For example, in the picture we can see `Q135`, `SG1_1` and so on. How can I specify for the whole dataset if a variable ends at `_L`, then for the same variable ending at `_RT` should remain as it is, otherwise the variable ending at `_RT` should be coded as `NA`.
I tried this but it only returns NAs

```
ifelse(grepl("//b_L" ==1, df), "//b_RT" , NA)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Evgenia! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It was actually a screenshot of part of the data, but maybe I can include a table in the post.

Comment: When you say "I have hundreds of variables and the names are not related. " it leaves me scratching my head wondering how you expect us to offer a sensible suggestion. The error was in the design phase of the survey and that's not an R problem.

Comment: It is not very clear in your example where does the `Q22_RT` comes from, and how do you link it to the `Q135_RT`, is it not supposed to be `Q135_RT` so that you leave it as it is ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a data frame of which the columns represent survey question variables. Each column contains two identifiers, namely: a survey question number (134, 135, etc) and a variable letter (L, R, etc). Because you provide no reproducible example, I tried to make a simplified example of your data frame:

```
set.seed(5)
DF <- data.frame(array(sample(1:4, 24, replace = TRUE), c(4,6)))
colnames(DF) <- c("Q134_L","Q135_L", "Q134_R", "Q135_R", "Q_L1", "Q134_S")
DF
#   Q134_L Q135_L Q134_R Q135_R Q_L1 Q134_S
# 1      2      3      2      3    1      1
# 2      3      1      3      2    4      4
# 3      1      1      3      2    4      3
# 4      3      1      3      3    2      1
```

What you want is that if Q135_L == 1, leave Q135_RT as it is, otherwise code it as NA. Here is a function that implements this recoding logic:

```
recode <- function(yourdf, questnums) {
  for (k in 1:length(questnums)) {
    charnum <- as.character(questnums)
    col_end_L_k <- yourdf[grepl("_L\\b", colnames(yourdf)) &
      grepl(charnum[k], colnames(yourdf))]
    col_end_R_k <- yourdf[grepl("_RT\\b", colnames(yourdf)) &
      grepl(charnum[k], colnames(yourdf))]
    row_is_1 <- which(col_end_L_k == 1)
    col_end_R_k[-row_is_1, ] <- NA
    yourdf[, colnames(col_end_R_k)] <- col_end_R_k
  }
  return(yourdf)
}
```

This function takes a data frame and a vector of question numbers, and then returns the data frame that has been recoded.

What this function does:

1. Selecting each question number using `for`.
2. Using `grepl` to identify any column that contains the selected number and contains `_L` at the end of the column name.
3. Similar with above but for `_RT` at the end of the column name.
4. Using `which` to identify the location of rows in the `_L` column that contain `1`.
5. Keeping the values of the `_RT` column, which has the same question number with the corresponding `_L` column, in those rows, and change values on other rows to `NA`.

The result:

```
recode(DF, 134:135)
#   Q134_L Q135_L Q134_RT Q135_RT Q_L1 Q134_S
# 1      2      3      NA      NA    1      1
# 2      3      1      NA       2    4      4
# 3      1      1       3       2    4      3
# 4      3      1      NA       3    2      1
```

Note that the `Q_L1` column is not affected because `_L` in this column is not located on the end of the column name.

As for how to define `questnums`, the question numbers, you just need to create a numeric vector. Examples:

- Your questnums are 1 to 200. Then use `1:200` or `seq(200)`, so `recode(DF, 1:200)`.
- Your questnums are 1, 3, 134, 135. Then, use `recode(DF,  c(1, 3, 134, 135))`.
- You can also assign the question numbers to an object first, such as `n = c(25, 135, 145)` and the use it : `recode(DF, n)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is extremely helpful. However, I am not sure how to define questnums. Should I do that before I run the function?

Comment: Please check the examples in my edited answer.